# android is there any way to test xml file on phone

Tags: android, android-xml

I need to know if there is any way that i can test my xml appearence on phone without running the whole app, i mean just the xml file without any action for anything?

Comment: Which app are you talking about?

Comment: Isn't it possible to open the XML file from within a file explorer?

Comment: not always, when i have tabs in my xml , the `Graphical Layout` doesn't show all the UI elements, and you know , on phone it will be nicer to check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no direct way to check the xml without recompiling and running on device.

But you can use graphical Layout editor to check the layout on approximated screens, or can create screen similar to your screen with same DPI and size.

and check it on graphical Layout editor.

NOTE: on device XML is just XML. where as when you compile the XML it is read and transformed to a view based code that is actually your UI.